# Swapping plus to minus and back

Tags: scala

This pretty much applies to any language, but since i'm learning scala and my prog is in scala...

I'm learning functional programming and have an equation whereby i need to go through a range of numbers and alternate between plus and minus foreach num. I've been using a procedural type function to do it, but wonder if anyone can think of a better way?

```
var s = 1;

def sign : Double =
{       
    if(s == 1)
        s = -1;
    else if(s == -1)
        s = 1;

    return s;
}
```

Thanks

Addendum:

I've changed to this as it's more succinct:

```
var s = -1;

def sign : Int =
{       
    s *= -1;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use -s (== multiplying each s with -1)?

Comment: The name `sign` is confusing. The keyword `return` is superflous, as well as the semicolons. The first declaration (Double) is confusing too. And see comments from Patryk Ćwiek.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning a value *that you're also changing*, which doesn't look like a good idea at the first glance. I'd go for pure function here, to avoid silly mistakes and such.

Now, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to just flip the sign?
If so, the method would be... Trivial:

```
scala> def flipSign(d : Double) = -d
flipSign: (d: Double)Double

scala> flipSign(3)
res3: Double = -3.0

scala> flipSign(-11)
res4: Double = 11.0
```

If you're trying to determine the sign (-1 for negative, 1 for positive, 0 for, well, zero), then:

```
scala> def sign(d : Double) = {
     |     d match {
     |     case x if x > 0 => 1
     |     case x if x < 0 => -1
     |     case _ => 0
     |     }
     | }
sign: (d: Double)Int

scala> sign(-3)
res0: Int = -1

scala> sign(212)
res1: Int = 1

scala> sign(0)
res2: Int = 0
```

**[EDIT]**

As @senia noticed in the comments, the `sign` can also have a very straightforward implementation:

```
def sign(d : Double) = d compareTo 0
```

Comment: You could implement method `sign` as `d compareTo 0`

Comment: @TobiasBrandt In general use it's trivial enough to be pointless, but I wasn't *quite* sure what the problem in question was, so it was added for clarity.

Comment: Um, sign is signum.  At least I guess that's why they call it that.